# Radius of an Open Ball inside the Intersection of an Open, Dense Subset and the Ball Around a Point in the Set

Tags: general-topology

Let $I \subseteq \mathbf{R} $ be dense and open.

Because $I$ is dense, for $x \in \mathbf{R}$,
$$\exists y\in I:y=I \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$$

Because $I$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ are open, $I \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is also open and thus $\exists \delta, \text{as a function of y, }\delta(y) \text{, such that}$:
$$B_{\delta}(y) \subseteq I \cap B_{\epsilon}(x) \tag{*}$$

**Question:** Is there a way to construct $y$ so that we can have an upper bound for $\delta (y)$ that makes (*) holds? In other words, can we find a $y' \in I$ such that:

$$\delta (y') < \alpha \to B_{\delta(y')}(y')\subseteq I \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$$

Comment: We can think of diameter of $I \cap B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$ to find an upper bound?

Comment: Wouldn't the interesting question be to find a lower bound on $\delta(y)$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh The only thing about the diameter $d$ of $I\cap B$ that I can come up with is that $d<\epsilon$. What do you think and how are you going to proceed with this?

Comment: @user25959 I am not sure about this. Obviously, one of the lower bounds is $0$. But I don't think there exists a largest lower bound.

Comment: @ASlowLearner I think an upper bound for your function $\delta \left( y \right)$ should be half of the diameter. Although I do not know if we can find a tighter bound.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Could you show me the construction?

Comment: @ASlowLearner, I am not talking about the construction of $y$. Rather, I am commenting about the choice of $\delta$ for each $y$. This choice, should be less than half the diameter of your set so that when you make open balls, these balls lie within the set completely. Now, when I say less than I mean some real number "less than" the half the diameter will work. Wherever your point may be, the choice of delta cannot exceed half the diameter.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh What if $y$ is less than half the diameter from the boundary of $I \cap B_{\epsilon}(x)$?

Comment: That is why I said, half the diameter is an **upper bound** for the choice of $\delta$. You will still have to choose your $\delta$ appropriately.

Comment: I am writing one answer for general metric space. You can do the same for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\left( X, d \right)$ be any metric space with the $d$ as the distance function. Consider your dense open subset $I$ and any point $x \in X$. Now for a given epsilon, consider $I \cap B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Now, if $y$ belongs to the intersection, in particular, $y$ belongs to $I$.

Therefore, $\exists \delta_1 > 0$ such that $B_{\delta_1} \left( y \right) \subseteq I$.

Also, $y$ is in $B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Therefore, $\exists \delta_2 > 0$ such that $B_{\delta_2} \left( y \right) \subseteq B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Now, if you choose $\delta = \min \left\lbrace \delta_1, \epsilon - d \left( x, y \right) \right\rbrace$, then $B_{\delta} \left( y \right) \subseteq I \cap B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$ which will do your work.

I have attached an image below for better understanding. In the image, $y$ is shown with $2$ open balls, one is relative to $I$ and other is relative to $B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Once you choose the lesser radius, you are done with what you want.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but is there a typo in the $6^{th}$ line?

Comment: Where do you think exactly is the error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\delta = \min \left\lbrace \delta_1, \delta_2 \right\rbrace$ instead?

Comment: Yes, that will also work. Even what I have written will work, since $\epsilon - d \left( x, y \right)$ is the distance of the point $y$ from the boundary of $B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Now, if you see carefully, the $\delta$ I have proposed guarantees that the open ball lies within $I$ (since $\delta \leq \delta_1$ and also it is less than or equal to the distance of $y$ from the boundary of $B_{\epsilon} \left( x \right)$. Hence, the open ball will be completely inside the intersection.

Comment: Ok so I am confused now. Did you mean both will work?

Comment: Your suggestion may work. That we will have to see.